# Apache 403 forbidden

Tags: apache-2.2, http-status-code-403

I have VirtualHost with `DocumentRoot "/home/blogs/domain.com"`

```
<VirtualHost domain.com:80>
 ServerName domain.com
 ServerAlias www.domain.com
 ServerAdmin admin@domain.com
 DocumentRoot "/home/blogs/domain.com"
 <Directory "/home/blogs/domain.com">
  AllowOverride All
  Allow from All
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm getting error `[Thu Apr 19 02:37:15 2012] [crit] [client 12.13.14.15] (13)Permission denied: /home/blogs/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file`

I have the following rights...

`/home/blogs/` `drwx------ (0700)`

`/home/blogs/domain.com/` `drwxrwxr-x (0775)`

Do I have to add blogs user to apache group? How can I do it?

PS: Why apache is looking for `.htaccess` file at `/home/blogs/`, but DocumentRoot is `/home/blogs/domain.com`

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the permissions of /home/blogs/, only the owner of the directory can see the contents. you may want to grant 750 or 755 permissions, so apache could read the contents.

The reason its looking for a /home/blogs/.htaccess file is a configuration option you haven't shown from your configs.  It is probably a `<Directory /> AllowOverride ...</Directory>`.